# How can I populate scatterlists from a buffer

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cryptoapi

Trying to use the linux crypto api to encrypt data coming in from a byte array buffer. Looking through the crypto folder source I came across sg_copy_from_buffer in scatterlist.c. It needs to know the number of entries as one of its parameters but I'm not sure what the unit of granularity is for one of the entries. Based on the incoming byte array, how can I decide the number of entries? This is for the latest version of the kernel 3.15.

Also, what does sg stand for? Its used when instantiating pretty much every scatterlist but intuitively I would think of using sl.

Answer (score 0):

"SG" stands for [scatter/gather](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectored_I/O).

SG lists do not have a unit of granularity; entries can have any size.

The number of entries in an SG list can be determined with `sg_nents()`.